# How to get data from a array list in vba

Tags: vba, arraylist

maybe this is a stupid question,but I cannot get data from an arraylist

```
Dim ArrList As Object
Dim str As String

Set ArrList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

ArrList.Add ("message")
Set str = ArrList.get(0) 'how to extract the message value
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it will get 'message':

```
Dim ArrList As Object
Dim str As String

Set ArrList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

ArrList.Add ("message")
str = ArrList(0)
Debug.Print str
```